# issue in google map integration in Objective-C iOS ( _ OBJC _ CLASS _ $ _ GMSPlacesClient , referenced from:)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

[Here is the screenshot for the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40EJj.png)

follows this tutorial https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start

In this tutorial error occurred after Step no. 4.

ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162)

pod v 1.1.1

xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)

> error   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSPlacesClient", referenced from:
>
> error clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

**1.** warning ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/harshilkotecha/IOS work/subViewDemo/Pods/GoogleMaps/Base/Frameworks/GoogleMapsBase.framework/GoogleMapsBase', framework linker option at /Users/harshilkotecha/IOS work/subViewDemo/Pods/GoogleMaps/Base/Frameworks/GoogleMapsBase.framework/GoogleMapsBase is not a dylib

**2.** warning ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/harshilkotecha/IOS work/subViewDemo/Pods/GooglePlaces/Frameworks/GooglePlaces.framework/GooglePlaces', framework linker option at /Users/harshilkotecha/IOS work/subViewDemo/Pods/GooglePlaces/Frameworks/GooglePlaces.framework/GooglePlaces is not a dylib

Comment: set other linker flag to "$(inherited)"

Comment: solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

go to linker flag and add "$(inherited)"
it will solve your problem